# Plotting in Python extracting only specific columns from a CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, matplotlib

EDIT: as suggested shortening the question:

Quite new to python and programming, and I would like to plot the 1st and 4th column into a log(x) log(y) graph. And honestly I don't knot how to extract only the two columns i need from this.

```
16:58:58 | 2.090 | 26.88  | 1.2945E-9  |   45.8
16:59:00 | 2.031 | 27.00  | 1.3526E-9  |  132.1
16:59:02 | 2.039 | 26.90  | 1.3843E-9  |  178.5
16:59:04 | 2.031 | 26.98  | 1.4628E-9  |  228.9
16:59:06 | 2.031 | 27.04  | 1.5263E-9  |  259.8
16:59:08 | 2.027 | 26.84  | 1.6010E-9  |  271.8
```

Comment: Using the `pandas` library will greatly simplify your life!

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please take the [tour]. You should break these two questions into two separate questions. Firstly, perhaps, you want to get your data in the correct shape. Then you want to worry about plotting it.

Comment: @nbeuchat Checking it out now looks nice so far.

Comment: @ShawnMehan Done

Comment: Good job. Now please edit this question and put in what you need out of the data. I'll give you an answer once I know what you need. You have given us your start state. Give us an example of what you want as output and explain anything you think is tricky.

Comment: Especially what the logarithm of 16o'clock would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", delimiter="\s[|]\s+", header=None, index_col=0)
df.plot(y=4)
```

[image]

*(Note that this ignores the logarithmic scaling because it's not clear what the logarithm of a time should be)*

Comment: Hehe sorry, I didn't comment on the log of time because I thought it's a joke. Log was not of 16 o' clock but to translate it into $\Delta t$ in [s], then $log(\Delta t)$. But I think I can do that step.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not use the excellent `pandas`, here is a steam approach.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import datetime as dt

test = """16:58:58 | 2.090 | 26.88  | 1.2945E-9  |   45.8\n
16:59:00 | 2.031 | 27.00  | 1.3526E-9  |  132.1\n
16:59:02 | 2.039 | 26.90  | 1.3843E-9  |  178.5\n
16:59:04 | 2.031 | 26.98  | 1.4628E-9  |  228.9\n
16:59:06 | 2.031 | 27.04  | 1.5263E-9  |  259.8\n
16:59:08 | 2.027 | 26.84  | 1.6010E-9  |  271.8\n"""

lines = [line for line in test.splitlines() if line != ""]

# Here is the real code
subset = []

for line in lines:
    parts = line.split('|')
    ts = dt.datetime.strptime(parts[0].strip(), "%H:%M:%S")
    num = math.log(float(parts[3].strip()))
    subset.append((ts, num))

# now there is a list of tuples with your datapoints, looking like
# [(datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 58, 58), 1.2945E-9), (datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 59), ...]
# I made this list intentionally so that you can see how one can gather everything in a tidy way from the
# raw string data.

# Now lets separate things for plotting
times = [elem[0] for elem in subset]
values = [elem[1] for elem in subset]

# now to plot, I'm going to use the matplotlib plot_date function.
plt.figure()
plt.plot_date(times, values)
# do some formatting on the date axis
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: A plot!]

Comment: I'm not sure what 

    `lines = [line for line in test.splitlines() if line != ""]`

does

Comment: It doesn't affect the solution for you. Its a mechanism to get the test data block into a format that mimics readlines from the file. You only need to worry about below the `real code` comment. That said, it generates a list of lines from `test` string.